# clearing values of sublist, clears values of parentlist in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
List<List<Integer>> li = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> li1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    li1.clear();// it’s clearing values of the parent List as well
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       if (arr[k][j].equals("H")) {
         li1.add(j);
       }
    }
    if (li1.size() > 0)
       li.add(li1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The others have nicely explained what went wrong in your code. The fine solution is not declaring the child list until you need it, that is, declare it inside the outer loop.

```
    List<List<Integer>> parentList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        List<Integer> childList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (arr[k][j].equals("H")) {
                childList.add(j);
            }
        }
        if (! childList.isEmpty()) {
            parentList.add(childList);
        }
    }
```

Now I believe that everyone can see that the different child lists cannot interfere with each other. And now you need no copying of any lists.

I made a few other minor stylistic improvements to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same reference and add in the parent list. Try to create new ArrayList inside the loop rather creating outside and clearing everytime.

```
List<Integer> li1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

instead of

```
li1.clear();
```

Comment: That was what I already suggested in my answer. Upvoted. :-)

Comment: @OleV.V. My bad I didn't notice that :(

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the reference of child list to parent list.
So when you clear the content of the child list, parent list will have nothing but a reference to the child list.

In short-

If subresult is `[1,2,3]` and you add this in result, then result = `[1,2,3]`

But now if you remove 3 from subresult, then result also becomes `[1,2]`

Similarly, clearing subresult also removes from the result list.

So in order to avoid that,

`result.add(new ArrayList(subresult));`

This creates a new List object with the values of the passed in list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the `List` or create a new `ArrayList` with its elements so that they do not refer to the same object.

```
if (li1.size() > 0)
    li.add(new ArrayList<>(li1));
```